# Iterating through columns in a dataframe to add to a Total Value column in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to iterate through some column names to add up the total value in a 'TotalValue' column. I get:

```
KeyError: 'TotalValue'
```

I have shown what the equation would look like if I typed it out to get the total.

```py
df['TotalValueByHand'] = df['Value_SCHD'] + df['Value_VBR'] + df['Value_IXUS'] + df['Value_MDIZX']
```

I would like to iterate through columns though because ultimately I plan to have a lot more in the list.  Sorry if the indentation comes out weird, it looked okay when I typed it.

```
stockList = ["SCHD", "VBR", "MDIZX", "IXUS"]

for s in stockList:
  
    df['TotalValue'] = np.where(df['Value_' + s] > 0, df['TotalValue'] + df['Value_' + s], df['TotalValue'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need `sum` only values greater like `0` use list comprehension for generate all columns names with [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) and `sum`:

```
stockList = ["SCHD", "VBR", "MDIZX", "IXUS"]

cols = [f'Value_{s}' for s in stockList]
df['TotalValue'] = df[cols].clip(lower=0).sum(axis=1)
```

If need only `sum`:

```
cols = [f'Value_{s}' for s in stockList]
df['TotalValue'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
```

Your solution is possible if create first column filled by `0`:

```
df['TotalValue'] = 0

for s in stockList:

    df['TotalValue'] = np.where(df['Value_' + s] > 0, df['TotalValue'] + df['Value_' + s], df['TotalValue'])
```